# How to tell python to take the larger number out of two duplicate rows

Tags: python, duplicates, conditional-statements

I'm trying to tell Python to take out of two duplicate rows the one with a larger value in a specific column. Concretely:

| Date | TtM |
| --- | --- |
| 2018-06-22 | 7 |
| 2018-06-22 | 28 |
| 2018-06-25 | 8 |
| 2018-06-25 | 15 |

I want python to take the row with "TtM 28" and to do this for every duplicated value based on "Date". So for cluster "2018-06.25" I want Python to take the row with "TtM 15". I have around 1300 duplicated values at different "Dates", so how can I tell Python to do this for every cluster of duplicates I have?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You may sort by column TtM and then drop_duplicates with keep=last, if rows order doesn't matter on can be restored then (for instance, by sorting again by column Date, if it's sorted now).

Comment: Use a dict with the dates as key to deduplicate the values. Either gather all TtM values into a list and then `max` each list, or do a `max` every time you try to assign to an existing key, depending on how you iterate over the data.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using pandas.

```
df.groupby('Date', as_index=False).max()
```

Comment: Yes, I am using Pandas. Am I correct to assume that like this Python looks at each cluster and determines which row has the most max() values? For example, if TtM is the same but another column has different values it takes the row that has somewhere the max() value? Thank you.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you meant by your question. But we essentially group the values by the date column, which means values in TtM with equal dates are grouped together. When we use .max() on the groupBy object we choose the highest values in each of the grouped TtM values.